# Value in Array is undefined TypeScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, foreach

I got an error in my foreach with an array:

```
function setRowData({ json }: NewType): void {
    // foreach key and value in json object
    // fill into an object
    // add object to array
    let tableRows: { id: string; key: string; de: string; it: string; }[] = [];
    Object.entries(json).forEach(([key, value]) => tableRows.push({
        id: key, key: key, de: value, it: (typeof value === 'string' ? value : "")
    }));
    setTableData(tableRows);
}
```

The error occurs on the line with the following content: `id: key, key: key, de: value, it: (typeof value === 'string' ? value : "")`

Does anyone know why the `value` variable called `value` inside my array is undefined?

In addition I post a photo of it and where the error occurs:
[image]

This one is the description of the foreach, why is the second type in the array undefined?
[image]

Comment: How does `NewType` definition look like?

Comment: I suspect the issue is that the function param should be `json` instead of `{json}`.

Comment: @Clarity It should not be json because i need to get the correct values of my json and without the curly braces { } it won't be possible anymore... but of course this fixes the error but doesn't help anything more hahhaha

Comment: So does `NewType` have a property called `json`?

Comment: @Clarity yes like that:
    type NewType = {
        json: any;
    };

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) you extract an array of key-value tuples.

In this case the problem is that typescript cannot infer the type of values in the object, so it types it as `unknown` (`[string, unknown][]`).

[image: object entries unknown]

The error is telling you that you cannot assign `unknown` to `string`.

In order to have it typed as `string` you must either specify it when using `Object.entries()`:

[image: typed as string]

```
const entries = Object.entries<string>(json);
```

Or you should specify in your `NewType` that json is an object with only `string` as values (using typescript's `Record`: `Record<string, string>`)

Comment: if I use entries instead of Object.entries with your defined variable, then I can't specify the other stuff like key, value anymore... :/

Comment: Ah thanks Sandro, now it works if i say json is an object with only string as value.

As you said: json: Record<string, string>